# Using hibernate criteria, how do I retrieve results on a left join basis?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a fairly standard parent-child entity relationship using `@ElementCollection`, and it appears that zero-filter criteria fetches provide different results,, based on the FetchType. Here's the setup:

```
public final class Client {

    ....

    // Set of referrers.
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "client_referrers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client"))
    @Column(name = "referrer")
    @Type(type = "my.custom.URIType")
    private Set<URI> referrers = new TreeSet<>();

    // Set of redirects.
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "client_redirects",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client"))
    @Column(name = "redirect")
    @Type(type = "net.krotscheck.kangaroo.database.type.URIType")
    private Set<URI> redirects = new TreeSet<>();

    ....
}
```

I've seeded the database with 10 records, some of which have `referrers`, `redirects`, or neither. Then I've executed the following query:

```
    Criteria browseCriteria = getSession()
            .createCriteria(Client.class)
            .setFirstResult(0)
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .addOrder(SortUtil.order(order, sort));
    browseCriteria.list();
```

I've observed the following behavior:

1. If I use `FetchType.EAGER`, the above query returns 7 results, omitting those entities which have neither a referrer or redirect.
2. If I use `FetchType.LAZY`, all entities are returned (as expected).
3. If I add something like `setFetchMode("client.referrers", FetchMode.SELECT)`, only 5 results are returned, as it seems that DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY is applied *after* the first/max results are determined. This is essentially the same as the recommended `Collection result = new LinkedHashSet( session.create*(...).list() );` from [this FAQ](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems?_sscc=t#jive_content_id_Hibernate_ignores_my_outerjointrue_or_fetchjoin_setting_and_fetches_an_association_lazily_using_n1_selects)

Is there any way to build the above query so that I can use `FetchType.EAGER` and get all results, including those that do not have referrers or redirects? I'd like to avoid HQL if possible.

Comment: The reason I'd prefer eager, is because accessing the referrers or redirects in a lazy-loaded scenario opens a database connection, and doesn't necessarily close it, resulting in database connection pool exhaustion. This gets tricky as I feed this entity through a serializer like jackson.

Comment: Have you tried setFetchMode("client.referrers", FetchMode.EAGER)?